# Code in C++ will not accept no and stop the program

Tags: c++, loops, reboot

I have tried many things and i can not seem to figure out why this program will not stop the code if you select N when it prompts to try again or not.

I feel as though i had this working earlier, but i can not find any code from when it was working, and i see no reason this should not work.  Can anyone help out?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char color[10];
    char reboot, yes_no;

    start:
        cout << "What color is the light?\n";
        cin >> color; 

    //if the light is Green
    if (!strcmp(color, "green")) { 
        cout << "The light is Green, you may go ahead and drive thru the intersection.\n"; 
    } else if (!strcmp(color, "Green")) { 
        cout << "The light is Green, you may go ahead and drive thru the intersection.\n"; 

        //if the light is Yellow
    } else if (!strcmp(color, "yellow")) { 
        cout << "The light is Yellow, safely stop at the intersection, or proceed thru.\n"; 
    } else if (!strcmp(color, "Yellow")) { 
        cout << "The light is Yellow, safely stop at the intersection, or proceed thru.\n"; 

        //if the light is Red
    } else if (!strcmp(color, "red")) { 
        cout << "The light is Red, you need to stop.\n"; 
    } else if (!strcmp(color, "Red")) { 
        cout << "The light is Red, you need to stop.\n"; 
    } 

    //non recognised input
    else{
        cout << "\nYour input was not recognised...Would you like to restart? (Y/N)\n";
        cin >> yes_no;
        if(yes_no == 'Y'||'y'){
            goto start;
        }
    }

    //restart program
    restart:
        cout << "\nWould you like to run the program again? (Y/N)\n";
        cin >> reboot;
        if(reboot == 'Y'||'y'){
            goto start;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition is not well formed it should be

```
if( (reboot == 'Y') || (reboot ==  'y') )
{
    goto start;
}
```

As it is, it always evaluates to true since 'y' evaluates to true and `true || anything` always gives true.

Same thing applies to `yes_no` check.

**EDIT** Since you are having trouble, I made a simple program to test it more easily, this should work as expected:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char yes_no;

    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Enter 'N or 'n' to quit\n";
        cin >> yes_no; 

        if(yes_no == 'N'|| yes_no == 'n')
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I vaguely understand what you are trying to say, i am a beginner to C++.  I changed the code to work like suggested, but it still does not stop the code if i chose "N" when prompted

        //non recognized input
    else{
     cout << "\nYour input was not recognised...Would you like to restart? (Y/N)\n";
     cin >> yes_no;
    if( (yes_no == 'Y') || (yes_no ==  'y') )
    {
        goto start;
    }
    else
    {
     return 0;
    }

Comment: @user3330762 I took your code and applied my change and it works for me.

Comment: @user3330762 Added a smaller example, can you give it a try ?

Comment: Oh my!  I tested that and it worked, so i added it to the code and it works great now.  I see what you are saying now to have it ask for NO and if not, then reboot.

Comment: Thank you all so much, especially Eric.  I knew it had to be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

These 2 lines looks a bit strange

```
if(yes_no == 'Y'||'y') 
if(reboot == 'Y'||'y')
```

maybe you meant below instead??

```
if(yes_no == 'Y' || yes_no == 'y')
if(reboot == 'Y' || reboot == 'y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the real reason your code doesn't work - operator precedence and associativity:

```
reboot == 'Y'||'y'
```

always returns `true`, since it's parsed as `(reboot=='Y')||'y'`. If you want to test if `reboot` is equal one of the two chars, test it like that: `reboot=='Y'||reboot=='y'`.

That should fix your code. Although here are some advices:

- Don't use the `goto` statement. You can loop your code using loops (`while`, `for` or `do while`).
- If you're using `C++`, use `std::string` for storing text, you can then use `text=="some Text"` instead of testing the output of `strcmp`.
- For future reference on operator precedence, you can always check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence).